# How do you generate a PBEKey for Serpent in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm trying to support PBE for AES, Serpent, and TwoFish.  Currently I am able to generate an AES PBEKey in Java using BC like this:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC", provider);
PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec("Password12".toCharArray());
SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
```

but I can't figure out how to generate a PBEKey for Serpent, so I'm assuming its not possible out of the box.  How would I go about implementing this?  Is there a hook somewhere that I can just register my own SecretKeyFactory to handle Serpent keys?

Coincidentally, I have noticed that using an AES PBEKey (as generated above) for encrypting/decrypting with Serpent/TwoFish "works", but I have no idea what the repercussions are.  Could I just get away with using the AES PBEKey?

Comment: It looks like the PBEKeyFactory class in BouncyCastle is what holds the implementations of the various supported PBE schemes, but there doesnt appear to be any way to extend it without implementing your own Provider.

Comment: I think the key factory (for symmetric keys) should be quite independent of the algorithm where the key is used afterwards - these keys have no special structure, only a given size. As I understand, the *SHA* in the name indicates what algorithm is used to create the keys, not with what algorithm the keys can be used.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I believe this is exactly why I am able to generate an AES key and simply use it for other ciphers (since the key itself is simply raw bytes).  However, the problem is that the PBEKey that is generated also includes things like the IV size, which causes problems for some ciphers (like Blowfish) that dont match the IV sizes of AES.  Perhaps the best I can do is create a DerivedPBEKey which is built on top of a PBEKey built for AES with specific overrides for a handful of known ciphers to allow for manual specification of the IV size.

Comment: I don't really see where the IV is used here - do you mean the salt? The salt for the PBE is independent on the IV used for the encryption.

Comment: In the comment above I'm not showing the initialization of the Cipher, but if I do the above to generate a key, then do  the following for a Blowfish cipher an exception is thrown:
PBEParameterSpec parameterSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, 100000);
bfCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cd.key, parameterSpec);

The exception is "initialisation vector must be the same length as block size"

Comment: But why would you use a PBEParameterSpec, and not a BlowFishParameterSpec (or whatever type of parameters are used for a Blowfish cipher)?

Comment: Because at this point, the SecretKeyFactory has not actually generated the raw bytes for the SecretKey.  It actually only contains the password as a char array, and a IV and salt size as indicated by the BC implementation.  When I define the PBEParameterSpec and init the Cipher with it, it then generates the raw bytes for the key.  Or at least that is my understanding of what is going on...

Comment: Hmm, it looks like I have to test this. But as I understand it: You are giving the `SecretKey` object to your `Cipher.init(...)` method - the SecretKey (which you got from the SecretKeyFactory) contains everything which is necessary for the key (either the key itself, or all the parameters to create it when needed), thus the ParameterSpec you give to the `init` method is the parameters for the cipher, not any parameters for key generation.

Comment: That was my understanding at first as well :)  I just tested this again to make sure I'm not crazy, and if you dont specify the salt and iteration count in the initial PBEKeySpec(), then the key.getEncoded() only contains the password bytes and the key isnt in a usable form.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2297/discussion-between-senecaso-and-palo-ebermann)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussions with PaŭloEbermann (above), I put together the following solution.  It generates a PBE key for AES256 and then simply copies the required number of bytes from the generated key into a new SecretKeySpec(), which allows me to specify the desired algorithm and key length.  Currently I am salting the password AND creating a random IV on each call to encrypt.  My assumption is that the IV is unnecessary since a random salt is applied to each encrypted message, but I wasn't 100% sure so I added the IV anyway.  I'm hoping someone can confirm or deny this assumption, since if the IV isnt needed, then its bloating the size of the output from encrypt() for no valid reason.  Ideally I would be able to generate a PBEKey of variable length with no algorithm ties (as per [PKCS5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898)), but it appears I am bound to the key sizes defined in the available PBE schemes provided by the selected Provider.  This implementation is therefore bound to using BouncyCastle, since I was unable to find a PBE scheme that provided at least 256bit keys from the standard JCE provider.

```
/**
 * parts of this code were copied from the StandardPBEByteEncryptor class from the Jasypt (www.jasypt.org) project
 */
public class PBESample {
    private final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";
    private final String MODE_PADDING = "/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private final int DEFAULT_SALT_SIZE_BYTES = 16;
    
    private final SecureRandom rand;
    
    private final String passwd = "(Password){12}<.....>!";

    public PBESample() throws Exception {
        rand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    }
    
    private byte[] generateSalt(int size) {
        byte[] salt = new byte[size];
        rand.nextBytes(salt);
        
        return salt;
    }
    
    private SecretKey generateKey(String algorithm, int keySize, byte[] salt) throws NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException{
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwd.toCharArray(), salt, 100000);
        SecretKey tmpKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[keySize / 8];
        System.arraycopy(tmpKey.getEncoded(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);
        
        return new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, algorithm);
    }
    
    private byte[] generateIV(Cipher cipher) {
        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        rand.nextBytes(iv);
        
        return iv;
    }

    private byte[] appendArrays(byte[] firstArray, byte[] secondArray) {
        final byte[] result = new byte[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
        
        System.arraycopy(firstArray, 0, result, 0, firstArray.length);
        System.arraycopy(secondArray, 0, result, firstArray.length, secondArray.length);
        
            return result;
    }

    
    public byte[] encrypt(String algorithm, int keySize, final byte[] message) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm + MODE_PADDING);

        // The salt size for the chosen algorithm is set to be equal 
        // to the algorithm's block size (if it is a block algorithm).
        int saltSizeBytes = DEFAULT_SALT_SIZE_BYTES;
        int algorithmBlockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
        if (algorithmBlockSize > 0) {
            saltSizeBytes = algorithmBlockSize;
        }

        // Create salt
        final byte[] salt = generateSalt(saltSizeBytes);

        SecretKey key = generateKey(algorithm, keySize, salt);

        // create a new IV for each encryption
        final IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(generateIV(cipher));

        // Perform encryption using the Cipher
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParamSpec);
        byte[] encryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(message);

        // append the IV and salt
        encryptedMessage = appendArrays(ivParamSpec.getIV(), encryptedMessage);
        encryptedMessage = appendArrays(salt, encryptedMessage);

        return encryptedMessage;
    }
    
    public byte[] decrypt(String algorithm, int keySize, final byte[] encryptedMessage) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm + MODE_PADDING);
        
        // determine the salt size for the first layer of encryption
        int saltSizeBytes = DEFAULT_SALT_SIZE_BYTES;
        int algorithmBlockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
        if (algorithmBlockSize > 0) {
            saltSizeBytes = algorithmBlockSize;
        }
        
        byte[] decryptedMessage = new byte[encryptedMessage.length];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedMessage, 0, decryptedMessage, 0, encryptedMessage.length);

        // extract the salt and IV from the incoming message
        byte[] salt = null;
        byte[] iv = null;
        byte[] encryptedMessageKernel = null;
        final int saltStart = 0;
        final int saltSize = (saltSizeBytes < decryptedMessage.length ? saltSizeBytes : decryptedMessage.length);
        final int ivStart = (saltSizeBytes < decryptedMessage.length ? saltSizeBytes : decryptedMessage.length);
        final int ivSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
        final int encMesKernelStart = (saltSizeBytes + ivSize < decryptedMessage.length ? saltSizeBytes + ivSize : decryptedMessage.length);
        final int encMesKernelSize = (saltSizeBytes + ivSize < decryptedMessage.length ? (decryptedMessage.length - saltSizeBytes - ivSize) : 0);

        salt = new byte[saltSize];
        iv = new byte[ivSize];
        encryptedMessageKernel = new byte[encMesKernelSize];

        System.arraycopy(decryptedMessage, saltStart, salt, 0, saltSize);
        System.arraycopy(decryptedMessage, ivStart, iv, 0, ivSize);
        System.arraycopy(decryptedMessage, encMesKernelStart, encryptedMessageKernel, 0, encMesKernelSize);
        
        SecretKey key = generateKey(algorithm, keySize, salt);
        
        IvParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        // Perform decryption using the Cipher
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParamSpec);
        decryptedMessage = cipher.doFinal(encryptedMessageKernel);

        // Return the results
        return decryptedMessage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // allow the use of the BC JCE
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        
        final String message = "Secret Message";
        PBESample engine = new PBESample();
        
        byte[] encryptedMessage = engine.encrypt("AES", 128, message.getBytes());
        byte[] decryptedMessage = engine.decrypt("AES", 128, encryptedMessage);
        if (message.equals(new String(decryptedMessage))) {
            System.out.println("AES OK");
        }
        
        encryptedMessage = engine.encrypt("Serpent", 256, message.getBytes());
        decryptedMessage = engine.decrypt("Serpent", 256, encryptedMessage);
        if (message.equals(new String(decryptedMessage))) {
            System.out.println("Serpent OK");
        }
        
        encryptedMessage = engine.encrypt("TwoFish", 256, message.getBytes());
        decryptedMessage = engine.decrypt("TwoFish", 256, encryptedMessage);
        if (message.equals(new String(decryptedMessage))) {
            System.out.println("TwoFish OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A slightly cleaner approach was to extract the required bits from BouncyCastle's PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator.java and use it for the key derivation instead of relying on PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC.

Comment: why would i get unsupport algorithm with PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC